# How to implement a Control System when I have two parameters that control said system?

Tags: control, pid-controller, labview

I've got a system that uses two parameters, let's call them F and P, to control the mass flow rate of a substance flowing into a chamber. I need to control the concentration (grams per cubic meter) of said substance in the chamber. This system will be programmed in LabView 2020, which is a requirement of the client. My initial thought was to just choose a value for P and control the system with F using a single PID, but I think I can do better.

F and P can both be used to control the mass of stuff moving into the system, but in different ways. P controls how fast stuff moves to the mass distributor, and F controls how fast the mass distributor moves stuff to the sparge nozzle. Essentially F is fine control and P is coarse control, but total output is controlled by some function of both. A drawback of this system is that while I can set F and P, I can only measure F. I have to assume P acts according to what its set to.

I guess to make an analogy to the typical PID example, this is like a system with two different heaters and one thermocouple. I spoke with a colleague who works in control systems and he suggested cascading two PID controllers. After some thought, I came up with the following:

PID#1: setpoint is the mass concentration desired, measured process variable is the actual mass concentration, and the output goes to PID#2's setpoint, and also controls F.

PID#2: setpoint comes from PID#1, measured process variable is F, and output controls P.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Where I'm uncertain is using the output of PID#1 to control F while also acting as the setpoint for PID#2. I've never chained PID controllers.

Comment: Perhaps consider hiring a consultant who is competent in the associated mathematics, has excellent grounding in physics, and is imaginative? Suggesting chaining *separate* 'course' and 'fine' PID controllers fed by a single sensor but to operate sequential physical systems already worries me. Have you seen what time delays, and especially variable delays which are chained, do to PID control? (There's a book, *"Optimization Models and Methods for Equilibrium Traffic Assignment"* that shows some of just how complex this gets. Best wishes. I'm gone.) [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: I agree with @jonk, wile looking at your approach. I suspect you have no chance to get it stable by cascading PID in a loop like that. Though there is solution, by "imagination" h h.. Think backward, why the client had to have that larger and smaller orifice , while needing only one output. As jonk says, discuss with the client, what performance spec they have in mind to design the mechanism so, especially about the delay/control speed.

Comment: @All - *Please be nice* and comply with the site's [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) (CoC) in everything you write. Nothing snarky / sarcastic / condescending (or worse). Some comments here were deleted / edited to comply with the code. [Polite constructive criticism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756) is allowed in comments - with the emphasis on *polite* & *constructive*. If your comment includes the words "you" or "your", please especially check that it still complies with the CoC. Thanks.

Comment: @jay there aren't two orifices and the mechanism is already designed. It's a single piece of equipment that has two different controls on it: one knob puts more stuff in a queue, the other knob controls how fast that queue moves to the reactor. The output is the combination of "how much" and "how fast". Until now, the process has been controlled by manually turning knobs and watching what the output does, then adjusting as needed.

Comment: @BenS. Gotcha! I meant the valves by "orifice". I am not sure how much it will take you and I to understand both way. I do have a similar setup for chemical labs, for the Chromatography systems we make. We are controlling mL/min rate using highly nonlinear proportional valve, ex. hydrogen and nitrogen. The volume and flow rate are critical factor. We use a single valve in the system. So, in order to put the control in more linear and controllable range, we specify the "inlet" pressure, ex. 60psi from the hydrogen tank regulator.  It's like a main volume nob outside and a trim nob in the unit.